# Check if a vector has only non-negative values in R

Tags: r

I have a numeric vector x. How do I check if it consists only of non-negative values?

Comment: `all(rnorm(1000) >= 0)` (replace the `rnorm` with your vector)

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the person who did probably DV'd because this seems like a very basic question, and you haven't said anything about how you tried to answer the question for yourself. Did you read some basic R tutorials?  (You could have said e.g. "I know how to check whether a single element is non-negative (`x[i]>=0`), but how do I check whether *all* the elements are non-negative?")

Answer (score 2):

It is as simple as this:

```
if (all(x >= 0)){
   print("All values are non-negatives!")
   # Do something else
}
```

Hope it helps.